# Showing Final grade in numbers and letters C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Please help if u can I did some changes but still stuck at showing the output final grade :( I'm sorry I didnt post what's the exact problem(now i did). 
THIS IS THE ASSIGNMENT:
A teacher need to input grades and get final grades

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

double FinalGrade;
const int students=3;
const int grades=5;
void FillGrades(int[][grades],int,int);
void PrintGrades(int[][grades],int,int);
void GetFinal(int[][grades],int,int);

    int main()
    {
            double FinalGrade=0.0;
    int CSC212[students][grades];

    FillGrades(CSC212,students,grades);
    PrintGrades(CSC212,students,grades);
    double FinalValue[] = {0.05,0.1,0.2,0.25,0.4};
    GetFinal(CSC212,students,grades);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void FillGrades(int setofgrades[][grades],int pupils,int tests)
{

cout<<"Please enter grades for student 1 :"<<endl;

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 1 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[0][0];}while(setofgrades[0][0]<0||setofgrades[0][0]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 2 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[0][1];}while(setofgrades[0][1]<0||setofgrades[0][1]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 3 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[0][2];}while(setofgrades[0][2]<0||setofgrades[0][2]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 4 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[0][3];}while(setofgrades[0][3]<0||setofgrades[0][3]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 5 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[0][4];}while(setofgrades[0][4]<0||setofgrades[0][4]>100);

    cout<<"Please enter grades for student 2 :"<<endl;

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 1 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[1][0];}while(setofgrades[1][0]<0||setofgrades[1][0]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 2 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[1][1];}while(setofgrades[1][1]<0||setofgrades[1][1]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 3 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[1][2];}while(setofgrades[1][2]<0||setofgrades[1][2]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 4 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[1][3];}while(setofgrades[1][3]<0||setofgrades[1][3]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 5 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[1][4];}while(setofgrades[1][4]<0||setofgrades[1][4]>100);

    cout<<"Please enter grades for student 3 :"<<endl;

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 1 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[2][0];}while(setofgrades[2][0]<0||setofgrades[2][0]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 2 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[2][1];}while(setofgrades[2][1]<0||setofgrades[2][1]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 3 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[2][2];}while(setofgrades[2][2]<0||setofgrades[2][2]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 4 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[2][3];}while(setofgrades[2][3]<0||setofgrades[2][3]>100);

    do{cout<<"Enter Grade 5 :"<<' '; cin>>setofgrades[2][4];}while(setofgrades[2][4]<0||setofgrades[2][4]>100);
}
void PrintGrades(int setofgrades[][grades],int pupils,int tests)
{
    cout<<"Std"<<setw(5)<<"Att"<<setw(14)<<"Ass"<<setw(14)<<"EI"<<setw(14)<<"EII"<<setw(12)<<"FE"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<pupils;i++){
        cout<<i+1;
        for(int j=0;j<tests;j++){
            cout<<"      "<<setofgrades[i][j]<<"     ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
void GetFinal(int setofgrades[][grades],int pupils,int tests)

{   
    double a[] = {0.05,0.1,0.2,0.25,0.4};
    for(int i=0;i<pupils;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tests;j++){
            double FinalGrade=0.0;

           FinalGrade+=setofgrades[i][j]*a[j];
        }
    }

    cout<<"Std"<<setw(5)<<" Final Grade "<<endl;
   for(int i=0;i<pupils;i++){


    cout<<i+1;
    double FinalGrade;
    cout<<"    "<<FinalGrade<<endl;

   }


}
```

Comment: Asking questions here is the same as asking questions anywhere. Not sure why you think it's anything special. At least _edit_ your post and tell us exactly what problem you're, exactly what output you're expecting, exactly what output you're getting, and why you think it's wrong. You should also give us more context of what you're trying to accomplish,

Comment: The last procedure `GetFinal` seems to compute the `FinalGrade`, but doesn't store it anywhere.

Comment: You should fill the grades with a loop (they can be nested) and in `GetFinal()` what calculation are you trying to accomplish? You are basically doing `double FinalGrade = setofgrades[i][j] * (0.05 + 0.1 + 0.2 + 0.25 + 0.4);`

Comment: Edit your question and include: What you want to do, what is the problem (exact function or place on the code that is wrong), what input you place there, what is the expected output and the wrong output the program produced. Without those details, it is difficult to offer any kind of help

Comment: When you used a debugger, which line (statement) is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables used in that statement?

Comment: BTW, blank lines, spaces and tabs do not affect a program's performance, but when used correctly can make a program much more readable.  For example, one statement per line in `do { ... } while` loops.

Comment: You could use a `for` loop to enter grades:  `for(unsigned int grade_index = 0; grade_index < 5; ++grade_index){ cout << "Enter Grade " << grade_index << " : ";}`.

Comment: @BoPersson  the assignment includes that i need to store the final grade of each student and save the result is an array FinalValue.

Comment: @rlam12 You're right sorry.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious you're right I'm just new to this website and I had some difficulty! I've edited my post

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've been asked to store the final grade in an array called FinalValue! but I don't know how.. it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
void GetFinal(int setofgrades[][grades],int pupils,int tests)
{
    for(int i=0;i<pupils;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<tests;j++)
            double FinalGrade=(setofgrades[i][j]*0.05)
                             +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.1)
                             +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.2)
                             +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.25)
                             +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.4);
/* --> */ cout << "Final grade: " << FinalGrade << "\n";
     }    
}
```

You're not *showing* the final grade because there is no output statement that displays the contents of the final grade variable.

I'm not sure if you want that `cout` inside the loop or not.  The calculation is performed for each loop, but it is not stored anywhere.

Inside the loop would look like:

```
    void GetFinal(int setofgrades[][grades],int pupils,int tests)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<pupils;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<tests;j++)
            {
                double FinalGrade=(setofgrades[i][j]*0.05)
                                 +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.1)
                                 +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.2)
                                 +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.25)
                                 +(setofgrades[i][j]*0.4);
    /* --> */ cout << "Final grade: " << FinalGrade << "\n";
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The code inside the loop seems wrong (not by your fault, the OP posted it). it's basicaly `double FinalGrade = setofgrades[i][j]  * 1.0;`. I think there should be an array `double weights[] = { 0.005, 0.1, ...}` and then `FinalGrade += setofgrades[i][j]  * weights[j];`

Comment: @Bob__ I did like your example but when I put the output statement it gave all the final grades equal to zero

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks for taking time and helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some of your code and added the function to calc the final grades. There are a lot of improvements to make (starting from the parameters passed to the functions), but at least now it works.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include <limits>  // only for std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()


const int students = 3;
const int grades = 5;
const int MIN_GRADE = 0;
const int MAX_GRADE = 100;
constexpr size_t SS_MAX = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(); // You can use SS_MAX = 128 or something else

void FillGrades( int[][grades], int, int);
void PrintGrades( int[][grades], int, int);
void GetFinal( int[][grades], double[students], int, int);
void GetChar( double [students], char[students], int);

int main() {
    int CSC212[students][grades];
    double FinalValue[students];
    char FinalChar[students];

    FillGrades(CSC212, students, grades);
    PrintGrades(CSC212, students, grades);
    GetFinal(CSC212, FinalValue, students, grades);
    GetChar(FinalValue,FinalChar, students);

    return 0;
}

void FillGrades( int setofgrades[][grades], int pupils, int tests ) {

    for ( int i = 0; i < pupils; ++i ) {
        std::cout << "Please, enter grades for student " << (i + 1) << ":\n";
        for ( int j = 0; j < tests; ++j ) {
            int grade;
            std::cout << "Enter Grade " << (j + 1) << ": ";
            std::cin >> grade;
            while ( std::cin.fail() || grade < MIN_GRADE || grade > MAX_GRADE ) { 
                std::cout << "Wrong value, please enter a number between " << MIN_GRADE << " and " << MAX_GRADE << ": ";
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(SS_MAX,'\n'); // ignore what remains in buffer
                std::cin >> grade;
            }
            setofgrades[i][j] = grade;
            std::cin.ignore(SS_MAX,'\n'); // only one value per line entered
        }

    }
}

void PrintGrades( int setofgrades[][grades], int pupils, int tests ) {
    std::string border(45,'-');

    std::cout << '\n' << border << '\n';
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << "Std" << std::setw(8) << "Att" << std::setw(8) << "Ass" << std::setw(8) << "EI" << std::setw(8) << "EII" << std::setw(8) << "FE\n";
    std::cout << border << '\n';

    for( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ ) {
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << (i + 1);
        for( int j = 0; j < tests; j++ ) {
            std::cout << std::setw(8) << setofgrades[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << border << '\n';

}

void GetFinal( int setofgrades[][grades], double FinalValue[students], int pupils, int tests) {
    //double FinalValue[students];
    double credits[] = { 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.4 };

    for( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ ) {
        double final = 0;
        for ( int j = 0; j < tests; j++ ) {
            final += setofgrades[i][j] * credits[j];
        }
        FinalValue[i] = final;     
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    for( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ ) {    // You don't really need another loop...
        std::cout << "Student " << ( i + 1) << " final grade: " << std::setw(6) << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << FinalValue[i] << '\n';
    }   
}

void GetChar( double FinalValue[students], char FinalChar[students], int pupils) {

    std::cout << "\nFinal grades:\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < pupils; i++ ) {
        if ( FinalValue[i] < 60 ) {
            FinalChar[i] = 'F';
        } else if ( FinalValue[i] < 70) {  // what happened to E?
            FinalChar[i] = 'D';
        } else if ( FinalValue[i] < 80) {
            FinalChar[i] = 'C';
        } else if ( FinalValue[i] < 90) {
            FinalChar[i] = 'B';
        } else {
            FinalChar[i] = 'A';
        }
        std::cout << "Student " << ( i + 1 ) << " final grade: " << FinalChar[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```